# Notification.requestPermission() does not work on iOS in React JS app

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, firebase, notifications

I try to implement one of my first React JS app, i started by an existing JS app that i've done. I have to request to the user the permission for notification. In my JS app everything work ok even on iOS. When i try it in React it work only on Android and Web no iOS.

```
const requestPermission = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!("Notification" in window)) {
            alert("Notifications are not available on this device.");
            reject();
            return;
          }
      
        
      Notification.requestPermission()
        .then(async () => {
          const token = await getFCMToken();
          resolve(token);
          window.location.reload(true);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          alert("You've blocked the notifications. Please check your browser settings");
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  };


if(Notification.permission==="granted"){
    showFCMToken();
}
```

That is my code that i've try. I also try to use the messaging.requestPermission() but it gives me that is not a function.

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging, getToken } from "firebase/messaging";
import { getDatabase, ref } from "firebase/database";

const firebaseConfig = {
    ...
};


const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = getMessaging(app);
```

Those are the configuration that I use for firebase.